# Spawn background project on Amazon from Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-web-services, background-process

I have a Rails app on Heroku and I want to spawn a background process with [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), or some other similar service.  I do not want to pay for a worker dyno, and have heard that it is relatively cheap to run this process on Amazon.  I am not talking about a background process that is scheduled for a specific time - I want a certain process to be executed when a user does something on my site.  Would Amazon EC2 be the right tool for this, or is there a different Amazon tool?  And for whatever is the right tool, how can I spawn it from Rails correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is to just pay Heroku.

AWs is a good way to go as long as you're comfortable managing the deployments and configuring the environment. It's "relatively" easy, but I wouldn't say it's easy unless you  have some experience deploying and managing rails apps in production. You also have to worry about hosts being up, how many workers per host, memory, hardware failure, etc. Most people are using Heroku in the first place to avoid this kind of work. That said:

1) for resque, you just need to connect to the same Redis cluster. Workers on AWS will see the queues with jobs created by your heroku app

2) for delayed job, you need to be able to read/write to the same db. this should also be pretty straight forward.

The big risk here is that you need to be careful about syncing your code. You don't really want to be running 1 version of code on your webapp and another version in your workers. You'd want to be extremely careful to pass references only by id (watch out for delayed job serializing your objects into something the worker can't deserialize).

Comment: I am familiar with all those things in theory (hosts being up, workers per host, etc) but my experience actually deploying on EC2 is nil.  Is there a good guide I could follow that would basically let me achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I don't have a reference to one off the top of my head. It will be "exactly" the same as deploying any rails app to EC2. I bet Google finds better references than I do. The only difference is that you need to point both your heroku app and your stock rails app running in EC2 to the same datastores. If you're using Heroku-provisioned addons, you may need to get the credentials out of Heroku using `heroku config`